# Serving multiple image and PDF files not from static folder in one single page

Tags: flask, src

Locally I have two folders, `IMG` and `PDF`, they are in the same root folder, for example `C:\myuser\IMG` and `C:\myuser\IMG`. Each of them contains multiple images or pdfs. These files are not used for beautify the page but real content in the page. I store the path of each files in a MySQL table.

The logic here is that I click a button and a page shows. The code in the backend extract all the needed paths (assuming 10 paths in total) from the database. Multiple images and pdf are displayed in `<img>` and `<iframe>` tages respectively. The paths are supposed to be passed into the attribute `src`.

I tried to use `send_from_directory()`, but it only sends one file at a time. I also tried to directly pass the path value using `render_template()` but locally stored file are not allowed to load unless its the static folder, which I'm not using for storing files. (I'm not so familier with web development, is it normally recommended to use the static folder for storing css and javascript files to store a large amount of images and pdfs?)

The example code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h4>This is header 4</h4>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="row" >
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <ul>
        <p id="Descriptiontext">"This is the description"</p>
      </ul>
    </div>               
    <div class="col-md-8" >
      <img class="img-fluid" src = "" ></img>
      <figcaption>This is the caption</figcaption>
      <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src = "" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the example there are one `<img>` and one `<iframe>` needing `src`, in real environment it would be more than two. All the paths should be passed to the `src` at the same time.

Is there a method to manage this?

Comment: So if my understanding is correct you want to display iframe and img tag in a for loop right?

Comment: @KrkRamaKrishna not quite correct. Actually the page has more than one div. Some div display at least one imgs and some div display at least one pdf.